# Calculate polygon coordinates given a lat long origin, an opening angle and a distance

Tags: r, polygon, geospatial

Imagine you have an apple pie and you cut a slice from the pie. The centre of the pie is the equivalent to my origin lat long coordinate. The distance from the origin to the edge of the pie is my distance and my opening angle/azimuth is the width of the slice of pie.

I wish to calculate the coordinates along the circumference of the pie given that I have an origin lat long coordinate, a distance from the origin to the end of the  and an opening angle/azimuth, I guess this could be the radius. I have the origin so that's my initial point, I wish to calculate 7 points along the perimeter of the apple slice and then I can close the polygon using my origin again.

I have compiled the following code so far but I am not sure how efficient it is and whether it's suitable when I need to calculate the coordinates for approx 9000 apple pie slices. Is there a function that could simplify this computation?

I had this working but I now have an error within the '%>%' in the leaflet section which I can't figure out.

Any pointer (excuse the pun) would be warmly welcomed.

```
library(geosphere)
library(leaflet)
N <- 3L;
siteCoor <- matrix(c(152.707480, -27.702700),ncol=2L);
azimuth <- matrix(c(0, 120, 240), nrow = 1) # azimuths for each of the sectors
beamwidth <- c(65) # beamwidth of the antenna
lowerEdge <- azimuth - (beamwidth / 2) # left most bearing of the main beam
increment <- beamwidth/6 # number of degrees to incremet to the next point in the azimuth, always six points
endpoints <- matrix(c(0:6),nrow = 1) # no of points in the sector to calculate the endpoint coordinates for 
sectorAzimuths <- endpoints * increment
siteEndPoints <- apply(lowerEdge, MARGIN =  2, FUN = '+', y = sectorAzimuths) #takes the lowerEdge array and adds these values to sectorAzimuths
polygonCoor <- destPoint(siteCoor, siteEndPoints,2465)
res <- matrix(siteCoor,nrow(polygonCoor)+nrow(polygonCoor)%/%7L*2L*nrow(siteCoor),2L,byrow = T);res[rep(c(F,T,F),c(nrow(siteCoor),7L,nrow(siteCoor))),] <- polygonCoor;
m <- leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addPolygons(lng=res[,1],lat=res[,2], color = "#03F", opacity = 0.9, fill = FALSE)
m
```

Comment: IMHO you should really first think about whether it is better to calculate these coordinates using a coordinate reference system (CRS) that is more suited to the task. For those kinds of computations the CRS should be in metric units (meters) and preserve both angle and distance (all of which is not true for unprojected lon/lat coordinates). Even though the `destPoint` function uses ellipsoid paths it is only an approximation of true bearings. This obviously all depends on the accuracy you are willing to achieve here.

Comment: See, e.g. here http://www.geo.hunter.cuny.edu/~jochen/gtech201/lectures/lec6concepts/map%20coordinate%20systems/how%20to%20choose%20a%20projection.htm

Comment: Thanks TimSalabim, the accuracy is not hugely critical as the pie shape segments are used for representational purposes. If the bearings are out by 1-5 degs this is not the end of the world. The search continues for a more simplified version of this. Thanks once again.